# Continious buttonsignal by clicking (Python)?

Tags: python, html, flask, button

since I am new to Python, I have a question about a new project. I have to host a website via Flask, which has to be able to control a PiCar by clicking buttons on that website. My problem is, that I only get a single signal by clicking on a button right now. For my task I need a button that gives a signal as long as I click on that button.
Maybe one of you is able to help me or can give me some advice.

Thx in advance :)

Comment: Instead of doing "as long as you are holding the button", try sending a "button up" and "button down" signal.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.